# Send email with wp_mail from profile.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a button in the profile.php pages for every user in the back-end, in order to send an email via php.
I managed to do it correctly when I click the button in the profile user I'm logged into, but when I tried to do in other users, I got the wordpress error "Invalid user ID"
I used the hooks show_user_profile and edit_user_profile correctly but I think there is some issue with the POST method.
After this issue will be solved, I need to change dynamically the email with the user's email I'm into.

```
    function fileEmailNotification(WP_User $user) {

        ?>
    <h2>Invia notifica file</h2>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $to      = 'XXX@email.it';
        $subject = 'XXX';
        $body = 'XXX';
        $headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: XXX <XXX@XXX.it>' . "\r\n";   

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email Sent');</script>";
    }
        submit_button('Invia notifica');
    ?>  <form action="" method="post">
        </form>
        <?php

}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'fileEmailNotification');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'fileEmailNotification');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only works when you edit your own profile because you are missing two parameters in your form when you edit someone else's (not the logged in user)'s profile :

These 2 fields: **user_id** and **_wp_http_referer**

You can add them to your form like this :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php 
    $logged_in_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($logged_in_user_id != $user->ID) : ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?= $user->ID ?>"
    <?= wp_referer_field(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

However, i noticed that this code adds a form inside the default profile edit form and i think this will get you in trouble.

I'd suggest you to use a simple button linked to an ajax call.